# What does "MO" mean after the name of a US city?

Tags: usa, terminology

There are some places in US, that contain "MO" in their names. For example, Columbia, MO; Kirkwood, MO; Saint Louis, MO. So, what does MO mean?

Comment: All places in the US end in a two-letter code for the state.  It's just usually they are much more obviously related to the name of the state.  Unfortunately, 8 states start with M and MI already got used for Michigan.

Comment: Canada's provinces and territories have similar abbreviations, too, and the USPS and Canada Post have coordinated to avoid ambiguity, which is why NB is New Brunswick and NE is Nebraska.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie nonetheless, I can never escape confusion when I see *Ontario, CA.*  Nebraska actually *was* NB from 1963 to 1969, if the Wikipedia article is to be believed.  NL also trips me up routinely, since I lived in Amsterdam when Newfoundland and Labrador received its current name.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's the two-letter code of the state.

MO is Missouri.

[List of U.S. state abbreviations - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations)

You can learn them with this [geographical game of States of USA](http://jeux.de.merlan.free.fr/jeux/US_states.xhtml) or [text game of states abbreviations](http://www.sporcle.com/games/g/stateabbreviations).

Answer (score 11):

The state abbreviation (such as MO) is sometimes required because quite often there is more than one city with the same name in the US. There is a "Portland" in Maine and one in Oregon; Kansas City, Missouri and Kansas City, Kansas (same city, but the state line runs across the city), and [almost each state has it's own "Springfield"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield#United_States).

Comment: I must disagree with this reasoning; although it's true there are often multiple cities with the same name in the U.S., state names abbreviations are used almost without exception, even when there is only one.

Comment: @Flimzy It is extremely common; more uncommon than only one place in the US having the name.  There's a Los Angeles, TX.  There are five places named Philadelphia not in PA.  New Chicago, CA used to just be Chicago, CA.  I've actually checked a few, and so far only NYC seems to be the only unique city name in the US.

Comment: @Andy I have no idea what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @Flimzy "I must disagree with this reasoning; although it's true there are often multiple cities with the same name in the U.S., state names abbreviations are used almost without exception, even when there is only one."  My point is that there is almost never "only one" city with the name, so the reasoning in the answer makes 100% sense, contrary to the opinion in your comment.

Comment: @Andy Minot, ND ...?  I can't find any other Minots.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Ya, and?

Comment: @Andy You said the only unique city name was New York, and I found you another.

Comment: There are far more Portlands than just the two in Oregon and Maine.  But @Flimzy is correct: people are far more likely to use the state abbreviation out of habit than for any other reason.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie there are Minots in [Maine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minot,_Maine), [Massachusetts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minot,_Massachusetts), and [Mississippi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minot,_Mississippi).  I don't think there's more than one Rumney, though, (NH), nor Truth or Consequences (NM), Ann Arbor (MI), or Seattle (WA).

Comment: @Andy there are [New Yorks in a handful of other states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York). The name of the city in New York is "New York"; it's just commonly called "New York City" to disambiguate it from the state of the same name.

Comment: @phoog That's fine, but whether a particular city name is unique across all 50 states is not really the point.  The point is that there are enough that are not unique that the state needs to be explicit, as in the answer.

Comment: @Andy outside of postal addresses, it really doesn't need to be explicitly specified most of the time.  Probably 99 times out of 100 it's clear from context.  People use the state abbreviation more out of habit than anything else.

Comment: @phoog i disagree, especially in the context of travel where a visitor may not be familiar with the US, which seems to be what prompted this question in the first place.